# WCF streaming with windows authentication

Tags: wcf, streaming, basichttpbinding

Im using this binding

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="abc_Windows" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""   />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Im getting this error when calling it.

```
HTTP request streaming cannot be used in conjunction with HTTP authentication. 
Either disable request streaming or specify anonymous HTTP authentication.
Parameter name: bindingElement
```

Im using windows authentication and need large files to be uploaded and downloaded via this service. What changes should i do to avoid this error? Does any other binding works with streaming and windows mode authentication?
Kindly help.